# bash: sed regex ignoring string

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I have one of the 2 possible texts:

```
 myProg vFOO 3.1.2.11.1+build4 (Build time: Aug  7 2014 15:33:58)
 myProg v3.1.2.11.1+build4 (Build time: Aug  7 2014 15:33:58)
```

How can I ignore the whole "FOO" string in my sed regex?
So it'll print:

```
 v3.1.2.11.1+build4
```

I was using:

```
 sed -n '/myProg v/s/.*myProg v["FOO "]\([[:alnum:][:punct:]]*\).*/v\1/gp'
```

Thanks

Comment: Is there a reason you want to use sed? Would a native-bash implementation that required no sed at all be acceptable?

Comment: I think I previously wrote this code to support old AIX servers we had. Couldn't install newer bash nor use the `grep -Po`. sed was the better option I found.

Comment: I also preferred to do it in a single line as pipe manipulation

Comment: "In a single line" is easy enough using `=~` -- I did two operations just out of laziness (to unify the cases before invoking the regex, and thus reduce the complexity / testing requirements for same). "As pipe manipulation" -- well, if that fits for what you're doing; just be aware that it has a performance cost.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are making the extremely common mistake of using square brackets for grouping.  That's not what they do; they create a character class.  You are looking for regular round parentheses (which apparently need to be backslash-quoted in your dialect of `sed`):

```
sed -n 's/.*myProg v\(FOO \)\?\([[:alnum:][:punct:]]*\).*/v\2/p'
```

The initial `/myProg v/` which you had, while well-intentioned, didn't really serve a useful purpose; the above script will only print lines where the substitution is successful, anyway.

(The `/g` flag you had were simply not useful, as there would only ever be a single match on a line of input.)

This is assuming your `sed` accepts `\?` to mean "zero or one repetition".  If it doesn't, you can somewhat inexactly but safely trade a `*` wildcard instead.

Comment: +1: Addresses the immediate cause of the issue, and teaches skills applicable beyond sed. (I continue to consider sed the wrong tool for the job, but...)

Answer (score 4):

You don't need `sed` for this at all -- and when operating only on a single line, using bash builtins only is far faster than running an external program and reading its output.

```
s='myProg vFOO 3.1.2.11.1+build4 (Build time: Aug  7 2014 15:33:58)'
[[ $s = *" vFOO "* ]] && s=${s//vFOO /v}
[[ $s =~ (v[[:alnum:]][^[:space:]]+) ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
```

...emits...

```
v3.1.2.11.1+build4
```

Answer (score 1):

how about grep:

```
grep -Po 'myProg v\D*\K[\d.]*'
```

with `build...` info:

```
grep -Po 'myProg v\D*\K\S*'
```

with your text:

```
kent$ echo "myProg vFOO 3.1.2.11.1+build4 (Build time: Aug  7 2014 15:33:58)
 myProg v3.1.2.11.1+build4 (Build time: Aug  7 2014 15:33:58)"|grep -Po 'myProg v\D*\K[\d.]*'
3.1.2.11.1
3.1.2.11.1

kent$ echo "myProg vFOO 3.1.2.11.1+build4 (Build time: Aug  7 2014 15:33:58)
 myProg v3.1.2.11.1+build4 (Build time: Aug  7 2014 15:33:58)"|grep -Po 'myProg v\D*\K\S*'   
3.1.2.11.1+build4
3.1.2.11.1+build4
```

Comment: Assuming GNU grep? My impression is that that's still very rare outside of Linux -- not available even on very current OS X, f'rinstance.